# Coockie для поддоменов

Tags: cookie

Есть домен второго уровня и несколько третьего. (test,api,file)
На доменах третьего уровня api, file и второго кукки задаются как .domine.com, чтобы была возможность использовать их между доменами. На домене test.domine.com, кукки задаются с domine=test.domine.com. Вопрос в том, что браузер берёт самые старые куки, а новые уже не смотрит. Как можно реализовать правильность работы, чтобы при обновлении кук на test.domine.com он брал новую свежую куку, а не с .domine.com